# How to change it to a list not a 2x2 image square when its a smaller window

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so when its a smaller window / smaller screen , ipad , phone etc it will make the 4 images go into a list not in that 2x2 anymore

**CODE**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DelUZens</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .top-left {
        top: 10px; left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%
      }

      .top-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px; right: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%
      }
      .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%
      }
      .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <div class="section-links">
      <a href="teams.html" class="top-left">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon1.jpg" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>


      <a href="store.html" class="top-right">
        <img style="width: 100%;" style="height: 50%" src="icon2.jpg" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>


      <a href="sponsors.html" class="bottom-left">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon4.jpg" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>


      <a href="aboutus.html" class="bottom-right">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon3.jpg" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://pastebin.com/ffym3bdp

Answer (score 0):

**Not enough rep to post a comment**

You can, and probably should, use bootstrap for that.

Comment: @CreepyC Yes, it's basically just a bunch of CSS classes, so nothing advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I probably screwed up your code a bit, but the layout seems to work. Try this see if it helps.

The key is using in css "@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)".

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DelUZens</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
    .wrap {
      overflow:hidden;
    }
            .box {
         float: left;
         width: 20%;
         padding-bottom: 20%;
      }

      .top-left {
        position:absolute;
        top: 10px; left: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .top-right {
        position:absolute;
        top: 10px; right: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .bottom-left {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .bottom-right {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;

      }


      @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
         .box {
            width: 100%;
         }
         .box a{
            position: relative;
         }

         .top-left, .top-right, .bottom-left, .bottom-right {
            width:100%;
         }

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <div class="section-links">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
      <a href="teams.html" class="top-left">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon1.png" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
      <a href="store.html" class="top-right">
        <img style="width: 100%;" style="height: 50%" src="icon1.png" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
      <a href="sponsors.html" class="bottom-left">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon1.png" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
      <a href="aboutus.html" class="bottom-right">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="icon1.png" alt="" z:index=1>
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot dude , this helped me out heaps greatly appreciated

Comment: if it answers your ques, vote up the ans. :) and yes, as what @Pkarls said, its definitely easier with Bootstrap css, as all these has been done for you.